# Flutter ListView with nested TabBarView

Tags: widget, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to layout my flutter application so that it looks like:

```
-ListView
  -WidgetA
  -DefaultTabBarController
    -Column
      -TabBar
      -Expanded
        -TabBarView
          -WidgetB
          -WidgetC
```

So that the whole screen is scollable and that the contents of Widgets A, B, and C can change and the height of the screen is not fixed.

The only way I have been able to get this to work is by doing something like:

```
-ListView
  -WidgetA
  -Container (with fixed height)
    -Column
      -Expanded
        -DefaultTabBarController
          -Column
            -TabBar
            -Expanded
              -TabBarView
                -WidgetB
                -WidgetC
```

But I don't want to have a hardcoded height. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem, I think I'm on the right track using Flexible class instead of Column. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html I'm also using Slivers https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html with CustomScrollView instead of ListView https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html

Comment: so? Any solution?

Comment: @JoelHernandez unfortunately not, I abandoned this layout and opted to just take my users to a new view so I didn't have to worry about setting container heights.